# In Doctor Who: Face the raven, what was Ashildr's original plan?

Tags: doctor-who

If Clara had not taken the ticking clock off Rigsy the following would have happened,
- The doctor gets trapped with the teleporter bracelet
- Ashildr's work is done of capturing him so she removes the clock off Rigsy
- Anah would be revived as she was not dead

How would Ashildr maintain peace though?
The people would know Anah was not killed but captured by Ashildr.
Wouldn't they question their mayor's motives?

Did Ashildr have a plan for what would happen after Anah goes back to normal life?

Comment: Nice Question. Wibbly Wobbly, Plotty Wotty I believe...

Answer (score 3):

They may have questioned her **techniques** sure, but they may well have been okay with her **motive** - which was maintaining the safe haven for them.

By handing over the Doctor, Ashildr was ensuring the future of her refugee colony: considering the residents are suggested as being concerned primarily with having somewhere peaceful to live, this may have been acceptable to them.

Sure, they may have been pissed off that Anah was used in this way, and that they were misled - but once Anah is shown to be okay, Ashildr seems to have been banking that their concerns for their own safety would overcome their qualms about her morals.

Besides, she's still immortal and has the capability of setting a death raven on them... are they really going to argue?

Comment: And given that there were Cybermen, Sontarans, and Ice Warriors (just that we know of) taking refuge there, it's likely few of them would argue with any plan that puts the Doctor out of commission and far away from them.